# Interpolate WITHOUT using a well-known function

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I have two arrays with the same dimension, lets name it `x` and `y`.
When I plot them, `plt.plot(x,y)` the plot itself gives me back a continuous interpolation of my discrete data `x` and `y`.

How can I recover these interpolation from the plot?
Is there any other alternative to obtain more data in `(x,y)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyplot.plot()` connects points on the graph with a line. That corresponds to linear interpolation if the plot is not logarithmic.

Among ready made functions, look at `numpy.interp()`.

For theory, refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation